# How to locate an element using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I didn't recognize locator in given code to perform automation testing.

HTML of the element:

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.in/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.retu…%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&" class="nav-a nav-a-2" data-nav-ref="nav_ya_signin" data-nav-role="signin" data-ux-jq-mouseenter="true" id="nav-link-accountList" tabindex="25">
```

Error stack trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='nav-link-accountList']/span[3]"}
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.10 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-118FCQKH', ip: '192.168.43.44', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9), userDataDir=C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir5888_21816}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=73.0.3683.86, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 107d4a42af64419e98016e7927c7dde3
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='nav-link-accountList']/span[3]}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.Please provide some html code you are looking for an element as well the code you have tried so far.This would help other contributor to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

There is an id so use that as the fastest selector method

```
#nav-link-accountList
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below xpath to select the link

```
//a[@class='nav-a nav-a-2' and @data-nav-role='signin']
```

Or you should be good with

```
//a[@data-nav-role='signin']
```

CSS locator

```
a[data-nav-role='signin']
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are trying to `click()` on the element with text as **Sign in** on [amazon.in](http://www.amazon.in) and to achieve that you need to:

- *Mouse Hover* the element with text as **Your Orders** / **Account & Lists**
- *Click* on the element with text as **Sign in**
- You can use the follwing solution:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.amazon.in");
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-tools']/a//span[@class='nav-line-2']")))).build().perform();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='nav-action-inner' and text()='Sign in']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to click the third span element under the anchor element you have given. The XPath used which is giving the error is not for the element you've given.

The given element has an id. So you can directly locate the element by id.

**Using ID:**

```
Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();    
driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList"));
```

**Using Css Selector:**

```
Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#nav-link-accountList"));
```

**Using XPath:**

```
Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-link-accountList']"));
```